# Page not found while checkout using Paddle payment

Tags: payment, checkout, paddle-paddle

I'm testing the paddle locally but still getting the page not found while clicking on the pay now button. I created my subscription plans and put the plan id in the data-product attribute but still not working. Can anyone help me?

Also, my domain has been approved as well. But still, it is not working this checkout on production.

[image]

```
<a href="#!" data-product="810000" data-email="demo@gmail.com" class="paddle_button custome_checkout_btn">Pay Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Occurs when you don't call `Paddle.Environment.set('sandbox');`